# How to set a field to null in a django update statement

Tags: python, django

I have the following statement:

```
TrackTitle.objects.filter(pk=tracktitle_id).update(master_id=None)
```

I get the following error from this:

> FieldDoesNotExist at /mturk/remove
>   TrackTitle has no field named 'master_id'

However, if I change it to the field name itself (which is a foreign key):

```
TrackTitle.objects.filter(pk=tracktitle_id).update(master=None)
```

I get the following error:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'

How would I set `master_id` to null in an update statement?

My model is:

```
class TrackTitle(models.Model):
    ...
    master = models.ForeignKey(ItemMaster, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: Can you show us the models.py for TrackTitle?

Comment: Is your field nullable? Can you share your `TrackTitle` model?

Comment: @yrekkehs sure -- updated.

Comment: Are you sure you created the appropriate migration and run it against the DB?

Comment: Please show the model ItemMaster

Answer (score 8):

Try using get:

```
 try:  
   TrackTitle.objects.get(pk=tracktitle_id).update(master=None)
 except ObjectDoesNotExist:
   print("No track with the id")
```